# What is the difference for this C++ code with and without the parentheses?

Tags: c++

What is the purpose of the parentheses in the following piece of code? What would be happening if the parentheses were not there?  Sorry, I am new to C++.

```
void foo(int * xPtr) {
  (*xPtr)++;
}
```

Comment: Look at [operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Comment: It would dereference the pointer, and then increment it. You should invest in [a good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list?lq=1)

Comment: `*xPtr++` would be `*(xPtr++)`

Comment: `void foo int * xPtr  {
  *xPtr ++;
}` does not compile.  ;-)

Comment: (whether or not it compiles/runs)Adding parentheses adds code readability.

Comment: _@Ava_ Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

With the parentheses, you increment the object the pointer is referencing, without them, you are incrementing the pointer to the next memory address and THEN dereferencing it (which in this case would do nothing).

Answer (score 0):

If parentheses are not there then you are basically modifying the memory address stored inside `xPtr` and then dereferencing the pointer. So clearly this is not what is desired.

Say we want the value stored at memory location `1000` to be incremented, but

```
*xPtr++;
```

results in incrementing the memory location by 4 and then,value at memory location `1004` is accessed, assuming size of integer on the machine is `4 bytes`.

Answer (score 0):

`(*xPtr)++` will increment the thing `xPtr` points to.

Postfix `++` has higher precedence than unary `*`; without parentheses, the code would be parsed as `*(xPtr++)` - you're incrementing `xPtr`, not the thing `xPtr` points to.